# gcc 4.9.2 bug in -Wmissing-field-initializers?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, gcc-warning

I have an issue in this code - which can be copied 1:1 into a cpp file in order to test the behaving:

```
#include <atomic>

typedef struct
{
    char                sDateTime [20];
    char                sLogFileDirectory [300];
    char                sLogFileNameTemplate [300];
    char                sLogOutput [10][100];
    std::atomic<bool>   bReadyToFlush;
} LogEntries;

typedef struct
{
    LogEntries              leLogEntries [1] {};
} LogThreads;
```

Compiling with gcc 4.9.2 SLES 11 SP2 `g++ -std=c++11 gcc-warning-bug.cpp -Wall -Wextra -c` I receive these very strange warnings:

```
gcc-warning-bug.cpp:18:34: warning: missing initializer for member ‘LogEntries::sDateTime’ [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
  LogEntries    leLogEntries [1] {};
                                  ^
gcc-warning-bug.cpp:18:34: warning: missing initializer for member ‘LogEntries::sLogFileDirectory’ [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
gcc-warning-bug.cpp:18:34: warning: missing initializer for member ‘LogEntries::sLogFileNameTemplate’ [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
gcc-warning-bug.cpp:18:34: warning: missing initializer for member ‘LogEntries::sLogOutput’ [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
gcc-warning-bug.cpp:18:34: warning: missing initializer for member ‘LogEntries::bReadyToFlush’ [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
```

Adding the `{}` initializer in this line

```
std::atomic<bool>   bReadyToFlush {};
```

even g++ is complaining in the 1st warning about `LogEntries::sDateTime` then the warnings are gone.

The warning is also gone when I remove the `std::atomic<bool>` line. The code is very simple; when you have g++ 4.9.2 check it out - it is really very strange.

**EDIT:** Regardless to which `LogEntries struct` member I add the `{}` initializer the warnings are gone.

How can be this behaving explained? For me it is a bug...

PS:
I consider it as a bug:
Change the array specifier in this line to 1000:

```
    LogEntries              leLogEntries [1000] {};
```

g++ will produce 5'000 warnings! I would suppose that it does not really make sense to repeat the warning for each array value.

Comment: How about writing C++ style code? (`typedef struct { ... } name;` cannot be found in any C++ tutorial I know of)

Comment: @Walter: This is a project written first in pure C code for CUDA from NVIDIA. Since CUDA 7.0 was released last Tuesday I am now migrating step by step the code into C++11 standard. Thank you for the remark but this is for the moment not the point.

Comment: @Walter: I agree with Al. Making the trivial change that you suggest doesn't change the behaviour of the compiler. The OP's structure definition is after all valid C++.

Comment: @TonyK This was not an answer, merely a comment. Of course, it has no direct bearing on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

*The 1st case is now confirmed by GNU it is a bug but already fixed in gcc 5.0*

*The ICE [Internal Compiler Error] is now in the bug database* [GNU bug database](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/testsuite/g%2B%2B.dg/cpp0x/constexpr-array11.C?view=markup&pathrev=221620)

It seems to be a bug. I was now playing a bit around and I get after a modification the compiler message gcc stopped because of an internal error.

**UPDATE:** As requested the code which cannot be compiled by gcc. Compiler options: `g++ -std=c++11 gcc-warning-bug.cpp -Wall -Wextra -Werror -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fno-aggressive-loop-optimizations -c` - some options are there because GNU requests it for a bug report.

```
#include <atomic>

class LogEntries
{
public:
    char                sDateTime [20];
    std::atomic<bool>   bReadyToFlush;
};

class LogThreads
{
public:
    static LogEntries   leLogEntries [10];
};

LogEntries LogThreads::leLogEntries [10] {};
```

Compiler fails with this output:

```
gcc-warning-bug.cpp:16:43: internal compiler error: in gimplify_init_constructor, at gimplify.c:4007
....
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
Please include the complete backtrace with any bug report.
See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
```

I will prepare the sample code and submit it to the developer team. In my project the member `leLogEntries` is static.

When you remove the `std::atomic` line then it works --> problem in the `std::atomic` implementation?