# PHP mysql second query failing but with no error message

Tags: php, mysql

Everything works fine up until the second query `SELECT * FROM artist WHERE artID != ?`. The html elements appear correctly but `$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM artist WHERE artID != ?");` is showing false for some reason and therefore the if statement is exiting however, no errors are echoed.

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    include 'connection.php';

    if(isset($_GET["album"]))
    {
        /* If album was passed in the URL then get current values
            for that album */
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT cd.artID, artName, cdTitle, cdPrice, cdGenre, cdTracks FROM cd INNER JOIN artist ON (cd.artID = artist.artID AND cdID = ?);");
        if(!$stmt)
        {
            echo $conn->error;
            exit;
        }

        $albumID = htmlspecialchars($_GET["album"]);

        $stmt->bind_param('i', $albumID);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($albumArtID, $albumArtName, $albumTitle,
            $albumPrice, $albumGenre, $numTracks);

        $stmt->fetch();

        /* Create input fields */
        // Album Title
        echo "<div class=\"row horizontal-center\">" .
            "<input type=\"text\" value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($albumTitle) . "\" name=\"albumTitle\"/>" .
            "</div>";

        // Artist Name
        echo "<div class=\"row horizontal-center\">" .
            "<h6>By Artist:</h6>" .
            "</div>";

        echo "<div class=\"row horizontal-center\">" .
            "<select name=\"artID\">";

        /* Create option for current artist so it will be first in list */
        echo "<option value=\"$albumArtID\">$albumArtName</option>\n";

        /* Generate list of artists except artist currently associated with the album */
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM artist WHERE artID != ?");
        if(!$stmt)
        {
            echo $conn->error;
            exit;
        }

        $stmt->bind_param('i', $albumArtID);
        $stmt->execute();

        $stmt->bind_result($artID, $artName);

        /* Create options for artists that were found */
        while($stmt->fetch())
        {
            echo "<option value=\"$artID\">$artName</option>\n";
        }

        echo "</select>" .
            "</div>";

        // Album Price
        echo "<div class=\"row horizontal-center\">" .
            "<input type=\"number\" step=\"0.01\" value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($albumPrice) . "\" name=\"albumPrice\"/>" .
            "</div>";

        // Album Genre
        echo "<div class=\"row horizontal-center\">" .
            "<input type=\"text\" value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($albumGenre) . "\" name=\"albumGenre\"/>" .
            "</div>";

        // Number of Tracks
        echo "<div class=\"row horizontal-center\">" .
            "<input type=\"number\" value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($numTracks) . "\" name=\"numTracks\"\n/>" .
            "</div>";

        // Delete checkbox
        echo "<div class=\"row\">" .
            "<div class=\"col-2\">" .
            "<h6>Delete:</h6>" .
            "</div>" .
            "<div class=\"col-1\">" .
            "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"delete\" value=\"Delete\"/>" .
            "</div>" .
            "</div>";

        /* Create hidden field to submit the album ID with the form */
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" value=\"" . htmlspecialchars($albumID) . "\" name=\"albumID\"\n/>";
    }
    else
    {
        /* Send browser back to artists page if they somehow accessed
            the edit page without going through the "Edit" link next
            to an artist in the table. This would be the artName variable
            would not be sent via the URL.*/
        header("Location: artists.php");
    }
    ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
        <h6>Delete:</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1">
        <input type="checkbox" name="delete" value="Delete"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update"/>
</div>
```

Comment: close the first query http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php

Comment: are both `albumID` and `album` two different animals here? I see `name=\"albumTitle\"` and `$_GET["album"]`. I also don't see any form tags, so this tells me you're relying solely on GET arrays from some `href`.

Comment: You posted the same question hours ago. I voted to close it.

Comment: @AlBundy Nice catch Al; closed.

Comment: @AlBundy The problem is more narrowed down here and that other thread wasn't getting any answers anymore.

Comment: @Chay22 Thank you :)

Comment: Rewrite the question. Use an MCVE. For some it may appear to "tiresome" when you post code which is definitely not needed for the problem. I could once cut 800 lines down to 10 - [see the post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184431/gcc-4-9-2-bug-in-wmissing-field-initializers). It is **NOT** a way to repeat your question every 3 hours just because nobody answered....

Comment: @AlBundy I included all the code that may be needed considering the other post had cut down code and nobody had any idea what the problem was. However, someone on this thread sorted it after I posted all the code so it was clearly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try

```
if(!$stmt)
     {
     die("ERROR: " .mysqli_error($conn));
     exit;
     }
```

Comment: The guy already uses error checking. `echo $conn->error;` and that `exit;` of yours won't do anything really. You already made it "die".